# Issues with ordiplot3d NMDS in 3dvegan package

Tags: vegan

I am looking for some help here with this 3d NMDS code. I have 3 issues.

1. The layout of the plot moves significantly each time I execute the code.
2. The sites and species are sometimes far off of the plot.
3. The species text is often overlapping. How can I fix this?

I am unsure how to change the plotting environment to ggplot, so that might be out of the question.

```
library(vegan) 
library(vegan3d) 
library(tidyverse) 
data("dune") 
SiteID <- 1:20 
NMDS = metaMDS(dune,distance="bray", try=500, wascores = TRUE, k=3) 
NMDS1 = NMDS$points[,1] 
NMDS2 = NMDS$points[,2] 
NMDS3 = NMDS$points[,3] 
NMDS = data.frame(NMDS1 = NMDS1, NMDS2 = NMDS2, NMDS3 = NMDS3, SiteID=SiteID) 
NMDS_input <- metaMDS(dune,distance="bray",try=500,k=3,wascores = T) 
pl4 <- with(NMDS, ordiplot3d(NMDS_input, pch=16, angle=50, main="Fish ion level 3", cex.lab=1.7,cex.symbols=1.5, tick.marks=FALSE)) 
sp <- scores(NMDS_input, choices=1:3, display="species", scaling="symmetric") 
si <- scores(NMDS_input, choices=1:3, display="sites", scaling="symmetric")
text(pl4$xyz.convert(sp), rownames(sp), cex=0.7, xpd=TRUE) 
sii <- as.data.frame(cbind(NMDS$SiteID,si)) 
with(NMDS, orditorp(pl4, labels = sii$V1, air=1, cex = 1))
```

Comment: I really do not understand what you try to do. Most lines seem to be useless and all `with(NMDS, ...)` are meaningless. The last line should be `orditorp(as.data.frame(pl4$xyz.convert(sii[,2:4])), labels = as.character(sii$V1), display="sites", air=1, cex = 1)` – but you get the same output with `text(pl4)`. Alternatively, if you insist using `orditorp`, try `orditorp(pl4)` with extra arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. `labels` must be character variables in `orditorp`. We always assumed so, but this was not checked in `vegan::orditorp`. Latest **vegan** version in github will take care of this and will also work with numeric labels.
2. `ordiplot3d` returns projected coordinates (in 2D) and if you want to plot those, you can just use the `pl4` object that you saved and you do not need to use `pl4$xyz.convert`. This object will also be accepted in `orditorp`.
3. If you want to plot points that were not used in the original mock-3D plot, you must use `pl4$xyz.convert` for their 2D projection. This function will return the projected coordinates in a form that is directly accepted by standard **R** functions `text`, `points` (and some others), but they will not be accepted by `orditorp` (and I won't change this). You must make these into two-column matrix-like object; `data.frame()` will work.

Your example code contains a lot of un-needed code. The following is an edit with only necessary lines and fixes that make this example work with current **vegan** release.

```
library(vegan) 
library(vegan3d) 
data(dune) 
SiteID <- as.character(1:20) # must be character 
NMDS_input <- metaMDS(dune,distance="bray",try=500,k=3,wascores = T) 
pl4 <- ordiplot3d(NMDS_input, pch=16, angle=50, main="Fish ion level 3", cex.lab=1.7,cex.symbols=1.5, tick.marks=FALSE) # no with(NMDS,...)
sp <- scores(NMDS_input, choices=1:3, display="species") # no arg scaling in scores.metaMDS
text(pl4$xyz.convert(sp), rownames(sp), cex=0.7, xpd=TRUE)  
orditorp(pl4, labels = SiteID, air=1, cex = 1) # character labels w/points in the same location
```